# How to search for xml tag using bash linux

Tags: linux, bash

I dont have xml scarlet just bash and i have to acheive in bash only.
i have the tag h h in xml format that is the response from a soap project. i have to validate/check if the response have the below xml tag.if yes then do "nothing" else "notify the recipients by triggering an email.

```
    tag=<name>h</name> <name>h</name>
    
 if [[$tag == "<name>h</name> <name>h</name>"]]; then "nothing" else "something" fi ->didnt work
 if [["$tag" == "<name>h</name>\n<name>h</name>"]]; then "nothing" else "something" fi -->didnt work either.
```

used grep ,awk what wasn't able to achieve it. tag is not a file its just the string
please help

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
tag='<name>h</name> <name>h</name>'
echo $tag
if [ "$tag" == '<name>h</name> <name>h</name>' ];
then
        echo nothing
else
        echo something
fi
```